# Is it likely Ubuntu 11.04 will ship with the ~200 line "miracle" kernel patch?

Tags: kernel, 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do we get this magic performance-boosting 200 line patch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13562/how-do-we-get-this-magic-performance-boosting-200-line-patch)

The [Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_2637_video&num=1) article "The ~200 Line Linux Kernel Patch That Does Wonders" has created a lot of noise. It seems reports are [flooding](http://www.phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?t=27138) in that this patch noticeably increases responsiveness during aggressive cpu usage.

How likely is it that this patch will make it into the next version of Ubuntu? And will it be backported?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How do we get this magic performance-boosting 200 line patch?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13562/how-do-we-get-this-magic-performance-boosting-200-line-patch)

Comment: My question is not answered in that link.

Comment: @leann drew out the entire process and described that since the patch is relatively new it hasn't made it into the Kernel's upstream. The likelihood of it being included in Ubuntu is just about completely dependent on when the Linux Kernel (as upstream) includes the patch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The likelihood of it being included in Ubuntu is mostly dependent on if the Linux Kernel (as upstream) includes the patch in the stable release 2.6.38 which will go into Natty Narwhal.

It's possible the Ubuntu kernel team will patch the Ubuntu kernel in time for the release if they feel it's really warranted. But that's up to them. You can track what the kernel team does here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam

They often have meetings and discuss these sorts of things, the meeting minutes often contain the decision to patch certain things.

There is probably no chance that it'll be back ported, even if it's 200 lines, it's modifying key areas of kernel functionality which change all the time (making the patch hard to apply). If it were to go wrong, it'd be hard to fix. I'd say it would be almost impossible to accept a backport.

Comment: I would say that it also depends on what other distros are going to do.  For example it might get backported to the 10.04 LTS kernel (2.6.32), because that is a long term support kernel upstream, and is also used by RHEL 6 for example.  A backport to 2.6.35 ("Maverick") is less likely, as that would have to be done & supported by the Ubuntu kernel team on their own.

Comment: This *has* been pulled into 2.6.38-rc1 so I expect it will be in the final (pending testing).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple.If the patch makes it to kernel 2.6.38, then Natty will have it as well.