# How to patch the kernel to decrease speed up Ubuntu desktop latency by a factor of ten

Tags: kernel, patch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do we get this magic performance-boosting 200 line patch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13562/how-do-we-get-this-magic-performance-boosting-200-line-patch)

I read about a recent patch for linux that cuts the desktop latency by a factor of ten. Is this patch available for ubuntu, and if so where. If not, how easy is it to patch a kernel. What tools do I need to accomplish this. The article is located [here at OMGUbuntu.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/linux-to-get-a-lot-faster-due-to-new-patch/)