# How to get a new Kernel patch the easy way?

Tags: 10.10, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do we get this magic performance-boosting 200 line patch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13562/how-do-we-get-this-magic-performance-boosting-200-line-patch)

I think most of us heard of the Speed Boost kernel patch [Here](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_2637_video&num=1). My question is how to get that patch on Ubuntu 10.10 ?

Do I have to compile a kernel (which i have never done before and the official Ubuntu documentation is advising against it) ?

Or Should I just wait for few days or weeks and it will be available in Automatic updates ?

Or it's just something that will be available in the future of linux distros ?

Comment: Discussion of this patch and how to get it has already happened. You have three options: wait (possibly a long time), find a kernel with this built in (they exist, see the thread) or patch it yourself and compile (again, see that thread).

Comment: Note that that patch makes your system **slower**, not faster, but it improves *responsiveness* instead.  So calling it a "Speed Boost" is very misleading...