# Getting the alternative to the 200-Line Linux Kernel patch to work

Tags: kernel, patch

Apparently, there is a comparable alternative to the 200-line [kernel patch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13562/how-do-we-get-this-magic-performance-boosting-200-line-patch)
that involves no kernel upgrade.

It is presented [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/alternative-to-200-lines-kernel-patch.html) and discussed [here](http://linux.slashdot.org/story/10/11/18/2246213/Alternative-To-the-200-Line-Linux-Kernel-Patch?from=rss&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+Slashdot/slashdotLinux+(Slashdot:+Linux)).

However, I am not sure if webupd8's solution (under the
section "Use it in Ubuntu") on Ubuntu actually works or not. In particular, one
commenter on ./ is saying he's getting an error message. Could anyone
post the "correct" method that actually works?

### Suggested solution:

Based on the comments I've read so far, the following seems to work.

(1) In `/etc/rc.local`, add the following lines to above `exit 0`:

```
mkdir -p /dev/cgroup/cpu
mount -t cgroup cgroup /dev/cgroup/cpu -o cpu
mkdir -m 0777 /dev/cgroup/cpu/user
echo "/usr/local/sbin/cgroup_clean" > /dev/cgroup/cpu/release_agent
```

(2) Create a file named `/usr/local/sbin/cgroup_clean` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
rmdir /dev/cgroup/cpu/$1
```

(3) In your `~/.bashrc`, add:

```
if [ "$PS1" ] ; then 
    mkdir -m 0700 /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/$$
    echo $$ > /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/$$/tasks
    echo "1" > /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/$$/notify_on_release
fi
```

(4) (To make sure the execution bit is on) execute

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/cgroup_clean /etc/rc.local
```

(5) Reboot.

Comment: Can you split this off into an answer and accept it? I started reading the accepted answer and got totally confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer above should indeed fix the terminal error message. Gödel, I'm not sure that I understood your point. I'll try to explain the change:

Since the default value of notify_on_release at creation of other cgroups is the current value of their parents notify_on_release setting, setting the value of /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/notify_on_release to 1 would make sure that every child cgroup had notify_on_release enabled and thus the release_agent would be ran. Unfortunately, when the last child cgroup of "user" was removed (by the release_agent), that folder would also be removed, leading to the error messages reported. A simple workaround is to enable notify_on_release for each cgroup individually at creation, keeping the parents setting disabled.

Hope that was easy to follow!

Edit: I'd have posted this as a comment to the actual answer, though it's seems I don't have enough reputation to do so (yet).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. On my system (Ubuntu Lucid with Kernel 2.6.32-25), the error message upon opening a gnome-terminal doesn't even appear, which led me to wonder if the proposed fix was necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

I applied this patch using the automated script on Web UPD8 to an Asus eee 1000H. I noticed a considerable performance increase in Google chrome with Flash applications running. Videos were smoother and less frame dropping.Gnome UI also is snappier and windows redraw faster. Very cool. [link text](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/script-to-automatically-apply-200-lines.html)

Comment: This script worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated instructions from Ricardo Ferreira

Start by editing your rc.local file, running `sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local` and add the following lines above `exit 0`:

```
mkdir -p /dev/cgroup/cpu
mount -t cgroup cgroup /dev/cgroup/cpu -o cpu
mkdir -m 0777 /dev/cgroup/cpu/user
echo "/usr/local/sbin/cgroup_clean" > /dev/cgroup/cpu/release_agent
```

Save and exit gedit. Now, make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

After doing this, edit the .bashrc file found in your home directory (gedit ~/.bashrc) and, at the end of this file, add:

```
 if [ "$PS1" ] ; then  
    mkdir -m 0700 /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/$$
    echo $$ > /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/$$/tasks
    echo "1" > /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/$$/notify_on_release 
 fi
```

One last thing. To make sure that cgroups are deleted whenever the last task leaves, run:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/local/sbin/cgroup_clean
```

And copy-paste this:

```
#!/bin/sh
rmdir /dev/cgroup/cpu/$*
```

Once again, save the file, exit gedit and make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/cgroup_clean
```

Done! Restart your computer to apply the changes.

Comment: But this only takes out the `echo "1" > /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/$$/notify_on_release` line and puts it into .bashrc. Isn't this necessary only when you get an error when executing `bash .bashrc`? Depending on the kernel version you are using, you may or may not get the error.