# Terminal error messages: bash: /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/2823/tasks: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

This is what I get when I start up the terminal:

```
bash: /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/2823/tasks: No such file or directory
bash: /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/2823/notify_on_release: No such file or directory
bash: /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/2823/tasks: No such file or directory
bash: /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/2823/notify_on_release: No such file or directory
sasa@sasa:~$***
```

I reinstalled 10.10 yesterday because of other problems, I didn't have this error message before. I have a separate /home partition, and new installation picked up almost all of the old settings, also those which I don't like, but it looks like that is not a problem or maybe I am wrong? Wouldn't ask if I knew! :) I'll be glad to post more info if someone needs it!

Comment: You haven't by any chance played around with that [cgroups thingy](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/alternative-to-200-lines-kernel-patch.html), have you?

Comment: Yep, looks like a mucked up cgroups thingy.

Answer (score 5):

Remove [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13928/getting-the-alternative-to-the-200-line-linux-kernel-patch-to-work) stanza from your `~.bashrc`:

```
if [ "$PS1" ] ; then 
    mkdir -m 0700 /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/$$
    echo $$ > /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/$$/tasks
    echo "1" > /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/$$/notify_on_release
fi
```

Comment: I haven't been playing around with cgroups,at least not intentionally.Anyway the problem is gone,don't know how or why.Thank you all!7