# Is it recommended to apply the new said-great 200 line Linux kernel patch?

Tags: kernel, patch

Nowadays I'm hearing a lot about the **new ~200 line path to Linux kernel** that is said makes sensible difference in performance.

Now, do anyone has experience on applying this path on his Ubuntu kernel?

I also saw an alternative way that claimed has a better result:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/59511828/cgroup_patch
chmod +x cgroup_patch
sudo ./cgroup_patch
```

What do you think this is? Is this validated?

I ask this question because I need more performance but I can't risk on stability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The famous "200 lines patch" will not improve the performance of your computer. However it *may* improve your user experience while having your computer heavily loaded : it improves the responsiveness of your desktop.

You could find some information at [Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_2637_video&num=1). There are also already compiled kernels available for Ubuntu 10.10 [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/download-kernel-2636-deb-compiled-with.html) but I recommend NOT testing this patch unless you fully understand what it does and how it works.

The patch will probably be included in Ubuntu 11.04, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13562/how-do-we-get-this-magic-performance-boosting-200-line-patch).

The alternative you present, as far as I know, only apply to processes launched from a terminal.

Comment: +1 for correcting my wrong expectation from the path.

Answer (score 4):

No. The supported method for getting updates is to wait for them to be available via Update Manager (which uses the software repositories) or a new Ubuntu version.

You are perfectly free to try this out, but you should know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: thanks, so you say it is not recommended for those who are not working on a testing or personal computer. right?

Comment: yes, for those who require stability, it is recommended to stick with what you have. It shouldn't take too long, however, until this patch arrives in the official installation.

Answer (score 1):

Well after I had applied the patch, I got a huge performance boost to my desktop. But I would still advise you to only use or apply this patch if you know what you are doing!

1. I would go [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/download-kernel-2636-deb-compiled-with.html) for a .deb package of with the patch plus more info.
2. I personally use [this](http://liquorix.net/) kernel on my system. It has the patch included plus some other tweaks for performance boost!

Option 2 is a little less stable I would say than option 1.

Answer (score 1):

I used the cgroup_patch on Ubuntu 10.10 on a eee pc 1000. I noticed Flash ran better in the Chrome browser. It appeared that less frames were dropping in the video. The UI feels snappier too when I open tabs in Nautilus and switch views. I guess on a system like a netbook where the cpu is pegged a lot you can visibly see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the cgroup_patch, and I have not had any stability problems.  The only time I have rebooted is when I have wanted too. Have I noticed a difference in performance?  I think so, but I don't have the numbers to back it up.  It does definitely seem faster though...

Answer (score 0):

I applied the patch to 2.6.36 and to 2.6.37...

Both cases worked 'better' but, like others, I don't have the numbers.

I am running Ubuntu 10.10, and did load the 2.6.38 kernel...

which includes the patch (as mentioned)...

THAT is worth the effort. There is soooo much that works better...

(NOTE: Kids go ahead and try this at home. Older scoundrels... read up on what you are doing, and find some young kid to help,  since Older scoundrels (like me) goof up a lot.Do find a good source, use the .deb's if you can find them, or check out reputable sources and sites.)

WebUpD8 listed a package at this url:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/how-to-install-liquorix-kernel-in.html

that I also tried and it worked (Had .38 already installed earlier)

You will find the next sudo apt-get update (or sudo apt-fast update if you have apt-fast installed), will cause another kernel update, later.

Again, never test things like this, unless you are ready (like having /home on separate partition, so you don't lose it)

I am an old (oooollllldddd) scoundrel and reload a lot since, I like doing things you shouldn't do at home without kids supervision...hehehe